# calculate how many images will fit horizontally with php

Tags: php, css

I'm building a small profile page in PHP.  How can I calculate how many images will fit within 960px layout given 3px padding around each image and a small margin of say 1px.  I should mention the thumbs should be over 100px x 100px.  So I guess I need to be able to calculate the size of the thumbs as well so that they fit evenly into the given width of the layout.

Comment: all of the images have the same size?

Answer (score 1):

Using maths.

```
floor(960/($imageSize-8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Php comes with GD, a library to mange images.

To calculate the size of an image: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php